# MySQL configuration changes corrupts existing databases

Tags: mysql

I have used MySQLv5.0.95 with MyISAM as default storage engine and I changed my.cnf to InnoDB as default storage engine and down-graded MySQL to v5.0.91.

When I am accessing my existing database tables. MySQL shows it doesn't exist.

Why my existing databases has been corrupted after applying my.cnf changes?

Comment: In general, you can't just switch database engines and you can't downgrade.  Reinstall MySQL 5.0.95 with MyISAM, backup your database, and attempt to restore your database to MySQL 5.0.91 with InnoDB.  You may have to make manual text changes to your backup for this to work.

Comment: Why are you running on 5.0? 5.5 has been out and stable for four years now.